# html element show value not clear on click

Tags: html

I have a form in which label name are shown in input field it self. Now problem is that when user enter date and m by mistake  click on that field it disappear.

I want that when user click on that field label will go off  but when user click after entering any useful record  the record should not go off.

please give any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean. Do you have an example somewhere?

Do you mean the label text disappears after focusing then unfocusing the input field? If so, have you tried using the placeholder attribute?